# Saving Entity does not update class-hierachy labels correctly

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I have an abstract superclass Report and two Subclasses SimpleReport and ExtendedReport, which I want to persist in my database.

If a SimpleReport is created, it has the labels "Report" and "SimpleReport" attached to it, as expected.

A user can modify such a SimpleReport, which leads to the SimpleReport becoming an ExtendedReport.

If I now save this ExtendedReport (using the same ID as the SimpleReport, because I just want to update it) it has the labels "Report", "SimpleReport"and "ExtendedReport" attached to it.

IMHO the label "SimpleReport" should be removed on save. I`m currently deleting the wrong label using a cypher query after saving the updated report.

I´m asking if there is a better way to archive this, if may approach is wrong or if this is a bug in ogm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for labels are as follows:

- any plain concrete class in the hierarchy generates a label by default
- plain abstract class does not generate a label by default
- plain interface does not generate a label by default
- any class annotated with @NodeEntity or @NodeEntity(label="something") generates a label
- empty or null labels must not be allowed
- classes / hierarchies that are not to be persisted must be annotated with @Transient

Therefore if you remove abstract from your base class, or add a `@NodeEntity` annotation, you will see the results you expect.

**Edit:**

The OGM does not remove labels when a class is renamed. Any additional labels are left intact.

- You can remove these manually using direct database access.
- You can declare a field with the `@Labels` annotation to manage adding/removing additional labels from an entity.

Comment: Thansk for your Answer, but I think you did not get the question correctly.

Comment: I try to explain it in other words. The problem is that a label of the class hierachy is not removed, after I change the type of it.  If I change the type of a "SimpleReport" to "ExtendedReport" and save it, the node has 3 labels, instead of 2. The labels are: "Report", "SimpleReport" and "ExtendedReport". So the "SimpleReport" label should be  removed.

Comment: Oh, yes I misunderstood. I believe you'll need to manually remove the superfluous label with CYPER -  the OGM does not track renaming of classes.